# Checkout: Mixed cart, split order and split payment

Tags: checkout, payment, order-splitting

Trying to workout the best approach to checkout(mixed cart) a specific product type with payment[1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting/5326#5326) and all other product types with payment[2].

I guess [splitting the order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting/5326#5326) will be one part, do you have any clues as to how I would then process split(1) with payment(1) and split(2) with payment(2) ?

My initial thoughts were to somehow create a product set that doesn't have a price and to then mask the cart total. Couldn't find anything on approaching that way though.

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress with your question?

Comment: split cart can be done using marketplace split cart addon please check http://webkul.com/blog/magento-marketplace-split-cart/

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the order is not really necessary since the payment applies more to the invoice than the order itself. Check out this answer [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799498/magento-create-partial-invoice-programmatically) on how to make a partial invoice. If you have 2 payment methods that would result in 2 invoices.

From the checkout point of view it depends on what kind of payment method you're using. The real issue would come from 2 payment methods that are both handled by 3th parties thus needing a redirect. But if your 'special product' should be paid using a banktransfer for example create an extension that first makes an invoice out of that product adding bank transfer as payment method and then sending of the rest of the amount to pay to, for example, a Credit Card gateway

Comment: Is any solution for this ?