# Splitting an order item into multiple orders items

Tags: cart

Is it possible to do the above and what is the best method for doing so?

Whether the order item is split in to multiple order items depends on whether the user has selected a radio button within the order process. I have been suggested to use a cart observer and listen for cart changes and make required changes that way.

Do you suggest the above or is there a better way of doing this?

Stephen,

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/split-order-into-seperate-orders-and-calculate-shipping-seperately-with-ups-and

Comment: I don't think multi shipping is what I need here. It seems far too complicated for what I require.

Would it be a good idea to put some logic in the checkout button code so that if it detects a certain radio button is checked, then make an AJAX call to add extra items in to the cart?