# Magento Shipping : Multiple Carriers with different Categories of Product

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

I'm working on a custom shipping module. The store basically sells two types of product like Heavy bulky product and normal goods. So the carriers we have tied up with will not carry all types of product. So suppose assume that a consumer orders both bulky product and normal goods so in the checkout while selecting the shipping method i will have show both carriers ie the carrier one which will shipping heavy bulky product and carrier which will carry normal goods.

As per my understanding currently the user can select only one carrier. Is it possible to override this. How can solve this issue. Can any one suggest a better approach to this problem.

Comment: On a very abstract level, you might wanna break the order in 2 parts, one order for heavy products and one for normal. This way you won't need to crazily re-write entire checkout process and order entity to save multiple carriers with one order.

Comment: Thanks Prateek. Is there any tutorial for the converting the order into 2 parts.

Comment: I haven't tried anything like this before, but these posts should give you a start : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/split-order-into-seperate-orders-and-calculate-shipping-seperately-with-ups-and, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767016/how-to-split-magento-order-for-downloadable-and-physical-product. Please do update which approach you end up following.