# Spiltting Magento Order Error: Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeItemByKey()

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, php-5.4, order-splitting

I'm spliting the magento order separately like different vendors, I'm fallowing the [Vinai Answer from previous post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting). But it's returning an error.

**Error:
 Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeItemByKey()**

`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` this class have this method but it's returning error **WHY**?

**my code is**

```
<?php

class Easylife_SplitOrder_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
{

    public function saveOrder()
    {
        $quote = $this->getQuote();

        // First build an array with the items split by vendor
        $sortedItems = array();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            //$vendor = $item->getProduct()->getVendor(); // <- whatever you need
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            //Mage::log($product->getVendor());
            $vendor = $product->getVendor();
            if($vendor != 0){
                if (! isset($sortedItems[$vendor])) {
                    $sortedItems[$vendor] = $item;
                    //Mage::log('vendor');
                }
            }
            //Mage::log('$vendor');
        }

        Mage::log('One');
        foreach ($sortedItems as $vendor => $items) {
            // Empty quote
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $quote->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
            }
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $quote->addItem($item);
            }
            // Update totals for vendor
            $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

            // Delegate to parent method to place an order for each vendor
            parent::saveOrder();
        }
        Mage::log('2');
        return $this;
    }

}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeItemByKey()
```

This method doesn't quite exist in Mage_Sales_Model_Quote in Magento and this is why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The function `removeItemByKey` can be found on the class `Varien_Data_Collection`. This means that is is a core function for collection objects. The class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` is not a collection object and so does not have this class.

I think what you want is `removeItem` this will take the id of the item you wish to remove and removes the item.

```
$quote->removeItem($item->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

What Vinai wrote is:

```
$quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
```