# Magento 1.9: Best option for managing order from Multi vendor

Tags: magento-1.9, module, multi-vendor

I want to build a Multi vendor is like amazon, ebay, flipkart where different sellers upload their products to sell And customer can choose products from different-different sellers. I am not using any 3rd party extension for this like [`Magento Marketplace Multi Vendor Module`](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html).

For managing seller, I provided a panel when they can manage their products and inventory. Also modify customer front-end for showing products through all available seller.

But I am a bit confuse with customer order scenario. The problem is, a customer can choose products from multiple seller means in customer cart i have multiple products from different-different seller. But now when customer place the order i want to notify each seller for placed order with all amounts (product, shipping) as per their store products.

For example we have 2 seller "A-seller" and "B-seller". now a customer select 2 product "Product-1" from seller "A-seller" (product price: $100, shipping: $5) and another product "Product-2" from seller "B-seller" (product price: $150, shipping: $10). And place the order for both product. So the total order amount is $265 ($100 + $5 + $150 + $10). Now i want to notify both seller for that order with their order products total. SO "A-seller" will be notify with $105 ($100 + $5) order amount and also manage separate invoicing and shipping status and "B-seller" will be notify with $160 ($150 + $10) order amount and also manage separate invoicing and shipping status for their product.

Here i have following solutions in my mind -

**Solution 1 -** Creating split order for both seller via maintaining Seller_Store_Id (display specific order in seller account) with order.

**Solution 2 -** place single order and creating multiple invoice, multiple shipment based on seller. Showing orders to seller with a layering approach means hide product, price which was not from his store or maybe using invoice data to show the amount.

Can anyone suggest me which one is the best approach or if you have any better idea then let me known?

A bunch of thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: solution 1 is better and also easy to implement because by this you can show seller to their own orders only

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/89430/45103

Comment: Custom coding is always appreciated but i would suggest using Unirgy Marketplace. Its using split Order for cart.

Comment: @ Kingshuk Deb  Unirgy Marketplace is a paid extension.can you suggest any free extension.