# Order Splitting in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, quoteitem, order-splitting

I am trying to split an order into multiple orders by referencing [Magento multiple order on one checkout or order splitting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting/#answer-4688).

I have extended `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage class` and written the new code in `saveOrder` method.

```
class My_Module_Model_Type_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
{
    public function saveOrder()
    {

        Mage::log('saveOrder() is called from mymodule....',null,'mylog.log');

        $quote = $this->getQuote();

        //First build an array with the items split by category
        $sortedItems = array();
        foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
        {
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $cats = $product->getCategoryIds(); //every product has single category
            foreach($cats as $category_id) 
            {
                //$vendor = $item->getProduct()->getVendor(); // <- whatever you need
                $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
                $_cat_name = $_cat->getName();

                if (! isset($sortedItems[$_cat_name])) 
                {
                    $sortedItems[$_cat_name] = $item;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($sortedItems as $cat => $items) 
        {
            // Empty quote
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
            {
                $quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
                Mage::log('removing from cart',null,'mylog.log');
            }
            foreach ($items as $item) 
            {
                $quote->addItem($item);
                Mage::log('adding to cart',null,'mylog.log');
            }
            // Update totals for categories
            $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();

            // Delegate to parent method to place an order for each categpry
            parent::saveOrder();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here, I am trying to split an order by categories. This newly written method is called when I click on *place an order* button.

**But in the above code, `adding to cart` text message is not printing in the log file. `removing from cart` message is present in the log file. (I think, it means item is removed from the quote but again that item is not added).**

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($items as $item) //..
```

Your $items variable seems not to be an array... see:

```
$sortedItems[$_cat_name] = $item;  // <-- is here an $item an array? No.
```

Comment: Then how should I insert item to quote object? should I insert $items directly to quote?

Comment: Try just: $quote->addItem($items); without foreach, you are actually inside one foreach loop.

Comment: ok let me try that but in the referenced link foreach is used.

Comment: I tried this but items are not adding to quote using $quote->addItem($items);

Comment: @vedu how you added item to quote can you please tell me