# Getting an item from quote object

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, quoteitem

I have extended `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` class via my custom module and overriding `saveOrder()` method. All this code is written inside `saveOrder()` method.

I am trying to get every item from the current quote object and save it to a new array.

Here is the code:

```
    $quote = $this->getQuote();

    //following line printing the quote id
    Mage::log("Quote id is : " . $quote->getId() , null, 'mylog.log');

    $myArray = array();

    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
    {
        $myArray[] = $item;
    }

    //====following lines doesn't log anything=========
    Mage::log($myArray,null,'mylog.log',true);
    Mage::log(print_r($myArray,1),null,'mylog.log');

    foreach ($myArray as $currItem) 
    {
        // Empty current quote
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
        {
            $quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
        }

        //inserting item to quote from myArray
        $quote->addItem($currItem);
    }
```

**But I think quote item is not inserting into $myArray and that is why `$quote->addItem` method is also not working here.**

Comment: What is your `this` class? Please add more code lines about your current class?

Comment: I have extended Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage class via my custom module and overriding saveOrder() method. All this code is written inside saveOrder() method.

Comment: Your code lines also make me confused. You tried to remove the current quote items and then tried to add them again. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try Below code and let me know if it is not working

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
       print_r($item->getData());
}
```

**Or**

In your Foreach loop

Write this

`$myArray[] = $item->getProduct()`

and try again

Comment: Hello @murtuza , after adding $item->getProduct() , I got following error for addItem() method : Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addItem() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item, instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product given

Comment: `$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $myArray [] = $item->getProduct();  }` try this one and let me know

Comment: I tried this but its is throwing same  above error only in network tab for saveOrder() method call.

Comment: Products are stored into $myArray.  Now those products from $myArray are not inserting into quote object using ->addItem() method. It is throwing : Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addItem() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item, instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product given

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if we overridden `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`, we don't need to use `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` to get quote items. This is because `$this->getQuote()` is equal to the quote checkout session:

```
    #app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php 

    /**
     * Quote object getter
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    public function getQuote()
    {
        if ($this->_quote === null) {
            return $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }
        return $this->_quote;
    }
```

So, shortly, your code should be:

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();
$myArray = $quote->getAllItems();

foreach($myArray as $item) {
    ....
    //Add new quote item
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item **/
    $quote->addItem($item);
}
```

**P.S:** Your code lines also make me confused. You tried to remove the current quote items and then tried to add them again.

Comment: Yes I am trying to split the order that's why I am trying to get items from the current quote and saving them into an array. Then using items from that array generating new orders.

Comment: So, my answer helped you?

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. :(

Comment: What is your current issue?

Comment: thank you for your help @Khoa . Check the issue [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133348/order-splitting-in-magento-1-9) . Please let me know if you need any explanation.

Comment: Seem it is a different topic. These answers in this topic cannot help you `Getting an item from quote object`? Please, accept an answer if it helps you to get an item from quote object - not splitting quote.

Comment: Ok. but ->addItem() is also not working. It is not adding a item to quote.

Comment: Yes I am using $quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId()); but facing the problem while adding back the item from my array. Bacause ->additem() is not working.

Comment: Try to use `$quote->removeItem($item->getId());`, and then, try to add again: `$quote->addItem($item)`.

Comment: Yes item is removed properly but it is not adding again. I just checked by Mage::log(count( $quote->getAllItems() ),null,'mylog.log'); In strating it displays count properly. after removing it shows count 0 but after that items are not adding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

                foreach( $cart_items as $items )
                {
                     if($items->getTypeId() != 'configurable')
                     { 
                            $pro_id=$items->getProductId();

                     }
                }
```

Comment: This code working on my client's live site.

Comment: thank you for your answer @krishna.. the problem is items are not adding to quote via ->addItem()

Comment: $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$product_info = array('qty'=>1);

$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($product_info));

$quote->save();