# How to split order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, onepage-checkout, order-splitting

**Edited Question**

After the suggestion from Khoa TruongDinh I made changes in `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()` and followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting) to implement order splitting but it's not working can anyone suggest me my mistakes.

**Previous Question**

I want to split order depending on no of items in Magento 2. I know in Magento 1.x it is possible by rewriting `saveOrder()` of `Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage` I tried the same way in Magento 2 but it is not working. I also tried to make changes directly in the core file for testing purpose only, but system not visiting `saveOrder()`.

Can anyone please tell me why this is not visiting.

I enabled Onepage Checkout configuration in Admin.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Magento uses API: `/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` on the onepage checkout. So, it's doesn't call your method.

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php*

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {
        $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
        return $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
}
```

You take a look this file to see more: `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php`

Comment: @AshishMadankar Do you able to split the orders?

Comment: @AshishMadankar  I would appreciate, if can you shed more light on how did you split the order

Comment: @AshishMadankar I want to split order in magento2 and I Saw system not visiting saveOrder(). Can you elaborate to split order in magento2

Comment: Your are right. I get api authorisatio error. Could you please help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313143/magento-2-split-order-based-on-product-attribute

Answer (score 1):

As per I can see in comments you already found a solution, but you never set this as solved, for others looking for a solution you can got an easy example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196669/magento-2-split-order-for-every-item/197800?noredirect=1#comment274010_197800) and another with a different solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164000/magento2-split-order-based-on-vendor/197907#197907)

Please Ashish if you think those are good approaches for get this issue solved let me know in order to help others.

Comment: Could you pls help me with it
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313143/magento-2-split-order-based-on-product-attribute

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had an experience to split order in checkout and I used a plugin to handle the `placeOrder` function with `around`:

```
public function aroundPlaceOrder(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    $cartId,
    $paymentMethod = null
) {

    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    ...
```

And then, split the quote by product SKU, of course, you can change the separation to any attribute you want.

I split the function into parts to make it easy to understand or modify, please take a look at https://github.com/magestat/magento2-split-order/blob/develop/Plugin/SplitQuote.php file to get more reference or details.