# How to get vendor wise order splitting in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, zend

Hi Friends I am using Magento 2.2.4 version so i need one help so below i mentioned scenario so please help me

> I had to split orders based on the vendor/seller selling that product.
>
> Like, for example, if someone orders Product1, Product2 and Product3,
>   where Product1 and Product2 are sold by Vendor1 and Product3 is sold
>   by Vendor2.
>
> Then, 2 orders with different Order Ids must be created where the
>   Order1 will have details regarding the order of Product1 and Product2
>   and the Order2 will have the details regarding the order of Product3.

i saw this below link but its not working

[Magento multiple order on one checkout or order splitting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting)

[Magento2 Split Order Based on Vendor](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164000/magento2-split-order-based-on-vendor)

event i am using : checkout_submit_all_after