# how can add Proceed to checkout for single single product in cart in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, payment

Magento provides proceed to checkout button in cart and when we click it
all the items in cart goes for checkout
like this.
[image]
And on payment page it is calculated for all products.
[image]

But i want checkout button for each product in cart.
I want my user to checkout each product individually.
I am sure there will be a solution for this in magento 2.

Comment: Please add single product into cart, why you have added more then one product into cart if you need to use proceed to checkout for one product.

Comment: please understand the question first

Comment: See if this thread helps https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196669/magento-2-split-order-for-every-item

Comment: No that didnt help me.i know it is possible cant find root