# Magento 2 splits order with shipstation with same order number

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, magento2.3.3, shipment

**Can we split orders into two types?**

We are using Magento2 stores.

We are using third party shipping service **Shipstations**

**Suppose, there are 2 types of products in my website Product A & Product B,**

When customer order Product A(any quantity) type product then from Magento will ship and that order information goes to shipstations and from shipstation users(admin) will decide shipping methods(carriers) - it ok for us.

In the same case, When customer order Product B(any quantity) type product then from Magento will ship and that order information goes to shipstations and from shipstation users(admin) will decide shipping methods(carriers) - it ok for us.

Now When customer order both Product A(2 items) & Product B(3 items) in a single order, Here we want to ship with different carriers like Product A must ship with Shipping A and Product B must ship with Shipping B

Please, anyone, know how it is possible.

Comment: You can use enable multi shipping future of magento.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya will you please check again my questions what is my questions ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding To achieve your things you have to do more customisation.

As per your requirement first of all you have to split order by item. because you have to generate different shipment for each item. so it is easy to manage shipment. so your first step to split order by item wise.

Second step if your extension **Shipstations** is provide functionality to select multiple shipping method & shipping address for each item then that's fine. otherwise you have to each default magento feature **multiple shipping** feature.

Also you have to manage Order, Shipment, Invoice etc. item wise back-end as well customer(front-end).

It is impossible to share code of your requirement because it is more customisation. so here i post some extension and links it will helpful to you.

1. [Split order by item extension](https://store.webkul.com/magento2-marketplace-split-order.html)
2. [Split order logic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196669/magento-2-split-order-for-every-item)
3. [Split order Github link](https://github.com/magestat/magento2-split-order)

I hope it helps!

Comment: ok let me ask with shipstations company about this