# How is order created using onepage checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, orders, onepage-checkout, totals

I was trying to split my order based on the seller selling the product. I was able to split my order by overriding the `saveOrder()` function. But, the order totals were not splitting. The totals appearing was of the complete order.

So, I want to know how are the totals of the order are saved so that the totals could be split.

P.S.- I am using onepage checkout.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

At `Mage_checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`, you can split **your order**

[@vinai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/766/vinai?tab=profile) Has been nicely explain on [Magento multiple order on one checkout or order splitting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/magento-multiple-order-on-one-checkout-or-order-splitting/4688#4688)

As you have using onepage checkout. may be your extension does not using 
`Mage_checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` 's `saveOrder`. then you need find the relative function/class which is do the same

Comment: I am able to split my order but the calculation of Subtotal and Grand total is not changed. It shows the amount of the entire order.
I tried the solution you provided in the answer. It did not work. I am not able to place order now. @AmitBera